# Enable normal user accounts to always force a system shutdown

Tags: macos, user-account, shutdown, administrator

I have a system with normal user accounts and an account with "administrator" privileges. Whenever that admin account is logged in, normal users can not shut down the system any more. I need to enable this, with the understanding that this can cause an admin session to be unexpectedly terminated.

How can I give normal users the power to force a shutdown (through the GUI) independent of whoever else is logged in at the time?

The target environment is macOS Ventura, 13.x.

Comment: AFAIK standard users can shutdown the system in such cases, they just need to confirm it. What makes this unusable for your situation?

Comment: When any other user is logged in, standard or administrative, the Mac can’t be shutdown without entering credentials for each account logged in. Not sure, in the least, why you’d want to enable this.

Comment: That would override admin and log it out

Comment: Why are the admin users left logged in?

Comment: Whenever an admin user is logged in, normal user accounts that try to shutdown the system are presented with a dialog that asks to enter credentials *of an admin user*. -- Metacomment: I don't know why the culture on Stackexchange seems to be so much in favour of "frame challenges" and asking "why is this even necessary". Can we please assume that there is a good reason for what I am asking, and I do not try to waste anyone's time here? It's just that there are privacy and security reasons for not detailing the scenario here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Think the key thing here is that in your case, the standard user and the admin user usually are different persons.